# AutoMapper and Windows Phone 7

Tags: automapper, windows-phone-7

Basics:

- Visual Studio 2010
- WP7 SDK 7.1 RC
- AutoMapper added to project via NuGet
- Ask for more!

Problem:

I'm getting the following error at runtime:
Could not load type 'AutoMapper.Mapper' from assembly 'AutoMapper, Version=1.1.0.188, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=BE96CD2C38EF1005'.

There seems to be an [open issue about this @ CodePlex](http://automapper.codeplex.com/workitem/5581), but i thought that i'd ask if anyone has found any solutions to this?

As always, i'm more than happy to provide any additional info required!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoMapper uses Castle Dynamic Proxy which requires Reflection.Emit which is not supported on the phone.

If you want this you're going to need to look at building it all yourself. In terms of getting round the lack of `reflection.Emit` (if you really do need it) then you should look at using [Mono.Cecil](http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/try-monocecil-if-you-need) to provide this missing functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that automapper is working on [silverlight edition](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/automapper-users/pVWORAMtZMc) so possible WP7/WP8 compatibility coming soon.

In the mean time there is a simple mapper library that you can use. It is very basic but probably meets most of your requirements for WP7 applications.

```
// Configure LazyMapper
Mapper.Create<SampleClass, SampleClassDto>();

// Perform mapping
var dto = Mapper.Map<SampleClass, SampleClassDto>(new SampleClass { 
    StringVal = "String1"});

Assert.AreEqual("String1",dto.StringVal);
```

Download at http://lazycowprojects.tumblr.com/LazyMapper